# Access violation reading location using 2D array mapped to 1D

Tags: c++, arrays, nearest-neighbor, neighbours

I am trying to check for neighbors in an array and without edge case checking for limits, the program will cause an exception. I need to check for at least bottomLeft, bottomRight, topLeft topRight corners. I am working in DirectXTDK and the function is for smoothing a landscape.

```
bool Terrain::SmoothenHeightMap(ID3D11Device* device)
{
    bool result;

    int index, nx, nz;
    float height = 0.0;
    int neighbours[8] = {}; // array starts at 0, inclusive
    int n = 8;

    /* Initialise corner of height map */ // 1.
    int bottomLeftCorner = 0;
    int bottomRightCorner = (m_terrainHeight * (m_terrainHeight - 1));
    int topLeftCorner = (m_terrainWidth - 1);
    int topRightCorner = m_terrainHeight * (m_terrainHeight - 1) + (m_terrainWidth - 1);

    m_frequency = (6.283 / m_terrainHeight) / m_wavelength; //we want a wavelength of 1 to be a single wave over the whole terrain.  A single wave is 2 pi which is about 6.283
    // m_terrainHeight is actually the z axis

    for (int j = 0; j < m_terrainHeight; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_terrainWidth; i++)
        {
            index = (m_terrainHeight * j) + i; 

            float sum = m_heightMap[index].y;

            // with more than 128 square dimensions, initial neighbours on bottom row might not exist
            // can refractor this better if it works

            if (m_heightMap[(m_terrainHeight * (j - 1)) + (i - 1)].x != NULL) {
                neighbours[0] = m_heightMap[(m_terrainHeight * (j + 1)) + (i - 1)].y; // top left
                neighbours[1] = m_heightMap[(m_terrainHeight * (j + 1)) + (i)].y;     // top middle
                neighbours[2] = m_heightMap[(m_terrainHeight * (j + 1)) + (i + 1)].y; // top right
                neighbours[3] = m_heightMap[(m_terrainHeight * (j)) + (i - 1)].y;     // middle left
                neighbours[4] = m_heightMap[(m_terrainHeight * (j)) + (i + 1)].y;     // middle right
                neighbours[5] = m_heightMap[(m_terrainHeight * (j - 1)) + (i - 1)].y; // bottom left
                neighbours[6] = m_heightMap[(m_terrainHeight * (j - 1)) + (i)].y;     // bottom middle
                neighbours[7] = m_heightMap[(m_terrainHeight * (j - 1)) + (i + 1)].y; // bottom right
            }




            for (int z = 0; z < n; z++)
            {
                if (neighbours[z] < 0 || neighbours[z] >= m_terrainHeight * m_terrainWidth) // if out of map, take y of current index for sum
                {
                    sum += m_heightMap[index].y;
                }
                else
                {
                    sum += neighbours[z]; // if exists, include in sum
                }
            }

            // smoothen based on neighbours
            m_heightMap[index].y = sum / 9.0f; // current point n is no. of neighbours +1 for current vertex point// total of 9 points in a 3*3 grid
        }
    }


    result = CalculateNormals();
    if (!result)
    {
        return false;
    }

    result = InitializeBuffers(device);
    if (!result)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The code as mentioned is used to smoothen terrain using a height map to go through points which are stored in structs. The following is the struct:

```
struct HeightMapType
    {
        float x, y, z;
        float nx, ny, nz;
        float u, v;
    };
```

which is being used by creating a pointer to it called `m_heightmap`.

```
HeightMapType* m_heightMap;
```

Comment: you are right modified as per guidelines

Comment: `(m_terrainHeight * (j - 1)) + (i - 1))` this value is out of bounds, when your error occurs.

Comment: What is `m_heightMap`? Use a std::vector or std::array, access it with `.at(index)` and wrap it inside a try catch, then you wouldn't have this problem. It's also recommended to use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`

Comment: Yes that is happening since I am at the beginning of the array, and checking for neighbors that do not exist for the first  few iterations rows and rest of corners

Comment: @nada The heightmap is a pointer to a struct containing information for that point on the landscape

Comment: @firepro20 An C-style array of struct? If so, make it a std::vector instead and follow above advice

Comment: Then you should't access a member of non-valid memory

Comment: @nada correction, it is a pointer to a C type struct, edited in previous comments

Comment: @RoQuOTriX that is exactly what I'm trying to avoid, however I am not sure how I would set the checks

Comment: `auto index = m_terrainHeight * (j - 1)) + (i - 1); 
if (index < 0 || index >= m_heightMap.size()) { // do nothing }
else { // do your stuff }`

Comment: @nada does this work if heightmap is a struct?

Comment: @firepro20 Of course you can have std::vectors of structs! It's C++!

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have the whole block of code, I can tell you the possible way of finding the bug.

As I can see in the screenshot, the line of error could not fond values or locations associated with the array. I recommend you to debug the code and step-over each for loop to get in-execution values of `m_terrainHeight * (j-1) + (i-1)`.
Possibly, the above expression is evaluating to an unexpected value.

Repeat the same line-by-line execution process on all allocations and executions to check whether or not you are getting expected values.

Please share the whole block of code for better understanding of the issue.

Comment: thanks for the advice, that is what I'm currently doing. I have modified the original post with all the function context

Comment: Yes... I can see it just now... I am working on the solution yet...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by checking for corners in the following manner:

```
if (m_heightMap[index].z + 1 >= m_terrainHeight || m_heightMap[index].z <= 0) {
                // if no neighbours, set height to that of current index/element
                neighbours[0], neighbours [1], neighbours[2] = m_heightMap[index].y;
                }
            else {
                neighbours[0] = m_heightMap[(m_terrainHeight * (j + 1)) + (i - 1)].y; // top left
                neighbours[1] = m_heightMap[(m_terrainHeight * (j + 1)) + (i)].y;     // top middle
                neighbours[2] = m_heightMap[(m_terrainHeight * (j + 1)) + (i + 1)].y; // top right
            }
            neighbours[3] = m_heightMap[(m_terrainHeight * (j)) + (i - 1)].y;     // middle left
            neighbours[4] = m_heightMap[(m_terrainHeight * (j)) + (i + 1)].y;     // middle right
            if (m_heightMap[index].z <= 0 || m_heightMap[index].z + 1 >= m_terrainHeight) {
                // if no neighbours, set height to that of current index/element
                neighbours[5], neighbours[6], neighbours[7] = m_heightMap[index].y;
            }
            else {
                neighbours[5] = m_heightMap[(m_terrainHeight * (j - 1)) + (i - 1)].y; // bottom left
                neighbours[6] = m_heightMap[(m_terrainHeight * (j - 1)) + (i)].y;     // bottom middle
                neighbours[7] = m_heightMap[(m_terrainHeight * (j - 1)) + (i + 1)].y; // bottom right
            }
```